# Typescript: Convert For loop to Promise and wait to resolve all

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await, promise

**ISSUE:** *save.emit() runs before all the iterations are completed in the below "for" loop which shows incorrect values of the addUpdate call inside loop.*

I am trying to convert a for loop to promise and then wait for each of those promise to resolve so that I can emit changes and close a popup.

Below, is a test code in which I want to print "`console.log("Print Before")`" first for each iteration and then at the end print "`console.log("Print After")`" once all iterations are done.

Any help on the syntax for this is really appreciated.

```
  convertForLoopToPromiseAndWait(someParameterOfTypeObject) {
    for (var test of someParameterOfTypeObject) {
      var testVariable = test.setValue;
      if (testVariable) {         
          dataService.addUpdateEndpointCall();
          console.log("Print Before");    
      }
    }
    console.log("Print After");
    save.emit();
  }

      async addUpdateEndpointCall() {
        const promise1 =  this.dataService.addCall().take(1).toPromise();
        const promise2 =  this.dataService.deleteCall().take(1).toPromise();
    
        await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
          .then(_ => this.save.emit());
      }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/m35Zqw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You should convert convertForLoopToPromiseAndWait to async method, and add await after for keyword. Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of

Comment: What is `addUpdateEndpointCall`? Does it return a promise? Then you should await it...

Comment: it does a service call and convert observable to promise and wait for both add & delete calls to finish before emitting changes. I have added the call in the question.

Comment: why not use rxjs operators?. In general it's better approach work with Observables than fight with Promises, asyncs and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have made a mistake here:

```js
const promise1 = await this.dataService.addCall().take(1).toPromise();
const promise2 = await this.dataService.deleteCall().take(1).toPromise();
```

You await promises. The results put in the variables `promise1` and `promise2` will then not be promises.

Don't you mean the following?

```js
      async addUpdateEndpointCall() {
        const promise1 = this.dataService.addCall().take(1).toPromise();
        const promise2 = this.dataService.deleteCall().take(1).toPromise();
    
        await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
          .then(_ => this.save.emit());
      }
```

Comment: My bad @md2perpe. You are right thats a typo. I did not mean to await those service calls but promises to be resolved at the end. I will update the code.

Answer (score 1):

Convert `convertForLoopToPromiseAndWait` to async method, then you can use `await` after for keyword and before `dataService.addUpdateEndpointCall();`

```js
async convertForLoopToPromiseAndWait(someParameterOfTypeObject) {
  for await (var test of someParameterOfTypeObject) {
    var testVariable = test.setValue;
    if (testVariable) {         
      await dataService.addUpdateEndpointCall();
      console.log("Print Before");    
    }
  }
  console.log("Print After");
  await save.emit();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't wait when testVariable is false. Say, there are 4 entries in someParameterOfTypeObject out of which testVariable is true for 3 and false for 1. Then, for the entry its false, it directly goes to await save.emit() before other iterations can be completed.

Comment: @Programmermid When testVariable is false, what is there to await? From this answer, with 3 testVariable=true cases and 1 testVariable=false case, I would expect "Print Before" to be printed 3 times and "Print After" + emit to happen once after all of the 3 individual calls to addUpdateEndpointCall complete. Are you trying to delay the `save.emit()` that you have inside `addUpdateEndpointCall`?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to make a list of promises and wait for them to resolve:

```
const promises = [];
        for await (your iterating condition) {
          promises.push(dataService.addUpdateEndpointCall());
        }
```

then use

```
await Promise.all(promises).then( this.save.emit());
```